# How do i loop through an array with for loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

```
<?php
$people = array(
          'maurice' => array ('name' => 'hillary',
                              'age' =>20,
                              'education'=>'degree'),
          'george' => array ('name' => 'florence',
                              'age' =>30,
                              'education'=>'diploma'),
          'Michael' => array ('name' => 'Andrew',
                              'age' =>10,
                              'education'=>'certificate')

                );

$countp = count($people);

          //echo $people['maurice']['name'];

for ($i=0; $i < $countp; $i++) { 
    for ($j=0; $j < $countp[$i]; $j++) { 
        for ($k=0; $k < $countp[$i][$j]; $k++) { 
            echo $people[$i][$j][$k].'<br />';
        }

    }
    # code...
}


?>
```

i am trying to loop through a multidimensional array with a for loop what could be the problem here. i have shared the code above.

Comment: post the expected result

Comment: why would you try with a `for` and not a `foreach`?

Comment: this will not work : `$countp[$i]`

Comment: I guess you could use `array_keys()` to fetch the key names and loop on that but, honestly, it feels like a irritating task. Unless there's a beer bet involved, just switch to `foreach`.

Comment: If no mode is given to the `count()` function then it returns the only size of the first dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

You should use foreach

```
foreach($people as $name=>$information){
 foreach($information as $informationKey=>$informationValue){
    echo $informationValue;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array is not made of integer indices. It is make of keys.

How about we rewrite your for loop

```
foreach ($people as $person => $data) { 
    echo $person . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Name : " .$data['name'] . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Age : " .$data['age'] . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Education : " .$data['education'] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

That shoud make it better!

Answer (score 0):

1. You are using strings as keys (instead of integers), so you need to access the array like `$people['maurice']['name']`, instead of `$people[0][0]`.
2. You only have two dimensions, so you don't need three loops
3. You should use `foreach()` http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php